# Quantas vezes 200 de reputação

Tags: suporte

Como poderia ser o código que pudesse informar quantas vezes eu consegui obter 200 de reputação no Data Explorer?

**Mais informações**

Já que estão surgindo respostas, gostaria também de saber quais dias estes 200 pontos de reputação ocorreram.

Comment: Se quer saber em quantos dias conseguiu 200 de rep pode ver isso no ver seu perfil (quadro de medalhas) click na engrenagem dê uma olhada na épicou ou legendário

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Encontrei [uma query já feita](http://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/query/39674/days-hit-rep-cap), e mudei o site de origem. Se colocares o numero da conta aqui no site vai funcionar:

http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/610079/dias-com-200-pontos

Comment: Muito bom, só note que esta query retorna todo score, o que não conta para nem sempre é contado pelo Capelo, Épico e Legendário. De qualquer forma ajuda muito ;)

Answer (score 10):

Nem precisa de código, pode ver isso em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/reputation (vai lá no fim do texto).

Comment: Aprendi algo novo hoje. 6 anos usando o sistema e nunca tinha visto essa "tela" (scriptizinho de programador para programador esse :)).